# Ping to Raspbrerry Pi fails

Tags: ssh, ping

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ on my network that serves as an SSH gateway. Everything works (I can access the internet) but no device can ping it.

I have fail2ban installed but no jails for ICMP/ping. I don't have ufw installed.

I can ping localhost from the device fine.

I really have no idea what the problem is. Other posts aren't any help (I've looked).

Comment: can you ping the `ip` of the ethernet or wifi (whichever you are using, you don't specify) from within the pi as well?

Comment: Does ping work between other devices on the same network or is ICMP restricted/filtered/blocked?